# Parsing html elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

In my (downloaded) HTMLs  i have in the top of every file executives mentioned (like Dror Ben Asher" in the code below):

```
<DIV id=article_participants class="content_part hid">
<P>Redhill Biopharma Ltd. (NASDAQ:<A title="" href="http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/rdhl" symbolSlug="RDHL">RDHL</A>)</P>
<P>Q4 2014 <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">Earnings</SPAN> Conference <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f38686">Call</SPAN></P>
<P>February 26, 2015 9:00 AM ET</P>
<P><STRONG>Executives</STRONG></P>
<P>Dror Ben Asher - CEO</P>
<P>Ori Shilo - Deputy CEO, Finance and Operations</P>
<P>Guy Goldberg - Chief Business Officer</P>
```

Further along the html these executives name reaccurs multiple times where after the name follows an text element i want to parse
Example

```
<P>
<STRONG> Dror Ben Asher </STRONG>
</P>
<P>Yeah, in terms of production in first quarter, we’re going to be lower than we had forecasted mainly due to our grade.  We’ve had a couple of higher grade stopes in our Seabee complex that we’ve had some significant problems in terms of ground failures and dilution effects.  In addition, not helping out, we’ve had some equipment downtime on some of our smaller silt development, so the combination of those two issues are affecting us.
</p>
```

For now i have a code (see below) which identifies one executive "Dror Ben Asher" and graps all the text which accurs after in the P element. But I would like this to work for all executives and for Multiple html files where different executives are mentioned (different company).

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/out'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Name', 'Answer'))
print('-' * 101)
for answer in soup.select('p:contains("Question-and-Answer Session") ~ strong:contains("Dror Ben Asher") + p'):
    txt = answer.get_text(strip=True)

    s = answer.find_next_sibling()
    while s:
        if s.name == 'strong' or s.find('strong'):
            break
        if s.name == 'p':
            txt += ' ' + s.get_text(strip=True)
        s = s.find_next_sibling()

    txt = ('\n' + ' '*31).join(textwrap.wrap(txt))

    print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Dror Ben Asher - CEO', txt), file=open("output.txt", "a")
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to tackle this challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could put the code in a function, to which you could pass the name you need as an argument and use that variable to construct your search strings.
for example:

```
def func(name_to_find):
# some code
    for answer in soup.select('p:contains("Question-and-Answer Session") ~ strong:contains("{n}") + p'.format(n=name_to_find)):
# some other code
```

and call it like so:

```
func('Dror Ben Asher')
```

Comment: Ok, but could it also go automatic for all names mentioned in the executives overview in the top of the html. Now i would need to call all the executives in all my HTML files.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what your code does. Do you want to take the names of the executives from the header of the html and search for text with their names in the rest of the html?

Comment: Yes and i would like this to be possible for multiple HTMLs (from different companies with different executives). Thank you for help!

Comment: you can first read all the names of the executives to a ```list``` of ```strings``` variable. and then go through them in a ```for``` loop, and for each name string you can use a function to find the text you need.

Comment: oeh i don't know how to translate this in my code, could  you give an example?

Comment: @nikos This sounds like it might be too large/broad for Stack Overflow, especially with the relatively small amount of information given. We don't even have a full example of the HTML, nor do we have a complete description of the format.

Comment: I have posted in dropbox an example : https://www.dropbox.com/s/uka24w7o5006ole/transcript-86-855.html?dl=0

Comment: Could i add something else to make my question clearer? @tohanov

Comment: @AMC could i add something else to.make my question clearer?

Comment: @nikos I can't think of anything specific, I think we would just need more of everything.